# increase the spacing between xtic in clustered bar graph (histogram)

Tags: gnuplot

Sorry if this looks like simple question (probably) but I searched around to get some solution with no avail.

I have plot a bar graph as shown (attached) here. My problem is to adjust the spacing between label for each xtic which overlap to one another. If you notice the bar graph I attached here, at the x-axis, the "Third label" and "Fourth label long" overlap to each other. Is there anyway to control the spacing so that the labels are not overlap? Additionally, I need the legends (ring1, ring2 and ring12) to be in italics. Since I am using "terminal pngcairo", is there way to do it in italics?

```
set terminal pngcairo size 550,350 enhanced dash
set output "xplot_ACF_ring1-ring2-head-plots2.png"

set macro
labelFONT="font 'arial,22'"
scaleFONT="font 'arial,12'"
scaleFONT2="font 'helvetica,13'"
keyFONT="font 'arial,18'"
########################################################################################

set ylabel "Time in (ns)"           @labelFONT
set ytic                    @scaleFONT 
set xtic scale 0                @scaleFONT
set size 1.0, 1.0

########################################################################################
ring1 = "#ff0000"; ring2 = "#7FFF00"; ring12 = "#0000FF"
set auto x
set yrange [65:90]
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1.5
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1
set boxwidth 0.9 relative
plot 'mal-cel-iso-bcm-ring1-ring2-head-bar-plot2.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ti col fc rgb ring1 ,\
     '' u 3 ti col fc rgb ring2 ,\
     '' u 4 ti col fc rgb ring12
```

The data for the above script is

```
Title         "ring1"   "ring2"     "ring12"
"First label"     70        76      77
"Second label"    68        71      69
"Third label"     76        72      68
"Fourth label long"   75        76      77
```

Below is the plot I get after executing the script. 
[image]

The re-edition of this post start here:

I would like to add error bar in this plot. The sample data is below:

```
Title   "ring1"         "ring2"         "ring12"
""      77.295326   2.2 74.829245   3.2 78.238016   2.1
""      77.613533   6.2 74.123269   1.5 79.704782   3.6
""      76.589653   2.1 71.704465   2.6 78.736618   4.2
""      75.996256   0.4 73.407460   3.3 77.290057   2.5
```

The third fifth and seventh columns are actually the error values.

I wish may thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean conventional errobars, like in http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/mgr.html? Please ask a new question for this, otherwise this question gets quite involved because the two points with the labels and the errorbars are related at all.

Comment: Yes sir. Thanks for the suggestion. I shall as separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an explicit option to prevent overlapping of labels.

In your example it is enough to decrease the white spacing to the left and right plot border a bit with

```
set offset -0.3,-0.3,0,0
```

which gives you with version 4.6.3:

[image]

Other options are e.g.

- Increase the canvas size (`set terminal ... size ...`). Note, that `set size` doesn't affect the image size, but only the size of the graph.
- For very long labels you can rotate the text e.g. with `set xtic rotate ...`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Additionally I have small question. How I can add the error bar for on top of each bar? I have the data. I may re-edit the question with the error values. I have searched around but could not figure our for the data arrangement shown in this post.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get around the problem would be to rotate the labels using:

```
set xtics rotate out
```

Or if you want to specify the rotation:

```
set xtics rotate by -45
```

Comment: Whoops, a bit too eager to help there!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the offset:

```
set offsets <left>, <right>, <top>, <bottom>
```

you can also find the following commands useful:

```
unset offsets
show offsets
```

remember that offsets can be constant or an expression

also remember that offsets are ignored in `splot`s.